# How can I create an executable with an executable inside?

Tags: python, windows, executable, vnc

I want to make an executable with VNC windows client inside, and when the app is executed, it prompts something, a message or something, and then opens the VNC client and closes itself, leaving only the VNC open...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to download a single file but have various files (applications, or whatever) in it, you better use an installation package.

If you're going to deliver a Python application (as per your tag) along with executable files, you might want to take a look at these:

1. [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)
2. [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is invoke a process [for the VNC windows client] from your application, *not* embed an executable within another (which doesn't make sense, by the way.)

For more information on how to do this, see [Subprocess Management](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) in the Python documentation.

Comment: Well, to embed an executable within another does make sense.

Comment: Well it *can*, but doesn't really in this context. :)

Comment: not, I want to embed the executable yes, so I can download into a computer that doesn't have VNC and use it only downlaoding my program.

Comment: @Shady, that's not really a good idea. The VNC assembly could have other system dependent libraries present, and then your idea wouldn't work.

Comment: @Shady: A better (more reliable, portable) solution is to check the system for the VNC client, and prompt the user with a dialog box if it's not present. The prompt can inform the user they don't have the required software, and ask them to click 'OK' to open their browser to the download page.

Comment: The system will never have the VNC, and prompting to download it's not an option, because when my program launch the VNC, it will launch with parameters, like, "-connect 192.168.1.1" or something similar... so, how can I do it? (and, the VNC I was looking to use, is one SINGLE executable)

Comment: @Shady, prompting to download should still be an option. The Subprocess Management documentation I reference in the answer shows how to invoke a process with arguments, **eg.** something like `subprocess.call(["path\to\vnc_client.exe", "-connect", "192.168.1.1"])`

Comment: @Rob, but I wont be able to determine where the VNC will be saved... Isn't me who will download it, so that's why I think I have to have the VNC embedded on the program.

Comment: @Shady: If you know the application binary isn't going to change on different systems (for example, 32-bit vs 64-bit) and doesn't require any 3rd party libraries, just deliver the VNC executable *with* your application (say, in a zip.) Note that doing this may have licensing implications.